# Through a for /f loop added spaces in the saved variable do not show up in the prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the possibility to Highlight every letter of a Word with the space key.
The delimeter is a for /f Loop Option. The Output of the variablenmae Word, do not show empty spaces. For example the varaiblenames Word, content is THEWORDISPAT is shown with the used code. Until I try to Output A THEWORDISPAT. In such a case the Output is fused ATHEWORDISPAT. I can not Point to search for what I Need. A non english native user.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set logic=13
for /l %%a in (1,1,%logic%) do (call :grapefruit %%a)
goto :eof
goto :main

:grapefruit
set count=0
for %%z in (%1) do (
set /a count+=10%3
set var[!count!]=%%z)

:main
set token=  THEWORDIZPAT
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%b in ("%token%") do (set word=%%b)
set alien=!word:~%var[10]%,1!
for %%y in (%alien%) do (echo|set /p =%%y)
pause > nul
endlocal disabledelayedexpasion
```

Comment: 1. it is unclear what you are asking, so please improve your descriptions; what is it you want, and what is actually happening? 2. `endlocal` ignores the argument, it merely restores the state before the most recent `setlocal`; 3. `goto :main` is never executed as there is a `goto :eof` before (exchange them?); 4. I suppose you do not want to move from `:grapefruit` immediately to `:main`; if I am right, you need to insert `goto :eof` at the end of the `:grapefruit` block; 5. I suppose you intend to use the modulo operator in `set /a`; if I am right, you need to double the `%`;

Comment: The Modulo Operator with set /a has been changed to 10%%3, therefore also the var[10] Counter to var [1]. The goto :eof has to be supplied so the :main Loop do not repeat on the last step a second time. There is an Output through the :main Loop and therefore it is executed. My Problem is still if i supplie the %token% with set token=  A THEWORDIZPAT the prompt Output is ATHEWORDIZPAT and not as i expect A THEWORDIZPAT. The space is missing.

Comment: Yes, `:main` *is* executed but I suppose not at the time you want to; the current execution sequence is: for each `for /l` iteration, `:grapefruit` *and* `:main` are executed; then execution is terminated (`goto :eof`); is that really what you want??

Comment: Without an Addition goto :eof command the called Label echoes %0 two times. First of the Label and the second of the file Name itself. In the :Grapefruit Label the for /l Iteration is the %1 in the Counter Loop and also called an additional second time. The Output would be THEWORDIZPATT with an additional T for the last Output. Therefore yes i really want the goto :eof

Comment: `%1` takes the first "word" from the parameter string. Use `%*` got get the whole parameter string or use `call :grapefruit "%%a"` and `%~1` to remove the surrounding quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Layouts for screen display is seperated in mainly two cases. First case languages and second case to define possible changes.

The solution below is possible but it is not with an upgraded example to the main example.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%A in ('echo prompt $H ^| cmd') do set BS=%%A
set "string=XA THEWORDIZPAT"
for /L %%A in (0,1,14) do (
for /f "tokens=* delims=X" %%b in ("!string:~%%A,1!") do (
set /p=%BS%%%b < nul)
pause > nul
)
```